# Getting a per-application/anonymous client id for REST API

Tags: rest-api, oauth, connected-apps

I want to get a desktop app to access the REST API.

I currently have set up a connected app and am using that personal client id.

Is there a way to get some kind of partner/anonymous client id so that users using the app do not have to set it up as a connected app and paste in their client id?

I see mention of a 'certified client application' at http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000Ha55EAC - any detail on that?

Comment: Other orgs can use your connected app setup as is, they don't need to setup their own copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your org a namespace, you can **Publish** the Connected App. Then you can bake the Client ID value into the desktop client which you distribute.

Comment: The connected app only needs installing if the org admin wants to use some of the access control features of connected apps. Otherwise nothing else is needed.